# Solve the initial value problem $\dot{\bf x}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \bf x+\begin{bmatrix} t\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

> Solve the following initial value problem: $$\dot{\bf
> x}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \bf x+\begin{bmatrix}
> t\\ 0 \end{bmatrix},\qquad  \mathbf{x}(0)=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1
> \end{bmatrix}.$$

This system can be solved by using the elimination method, but here I want to use another approach as following:

---

Let
$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},$ and
$\mathbf{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}
t\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$.
Note that
$$\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
\text{and}\qquad
(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Therefore, $e^{(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})t}=\mathbf{I}t+(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})t$, and
$$\begin{aligned}
e^{\mathbf{A}t}&=e^{(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})t}\cdot e^{\mathbf{I}t}\\
&=\mathbf{I}te^{\mathbf{I}t}+(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})te^{\mathbf{I}t}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
te^t & -te^t\\
0 & te^t
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, the complementary solution is 
$$\mathbf{x_c}=e^{\mathbf{A}t}\cdot \mathbf{x_0}=\begin{bmatrix}
-te^t\\
te^t
\end{bmatrix},$$
and the particular solution is 
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{x_p}&=e^{\mathbf{A}t}\int_0^te^{-\mathbf{A}\tau}\beta(\tau)d\tau\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
t+(t-2)e^t+2\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}$$
Hence, the solution is given by
$$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x_c}+\mathbf{x_p}=\begin{bmatrix}
t-2e^t+2\\
te^t
\end{bmatrix}.$$

---

But unfortunately, I find this answer is incorrect. I don't know where I'm wrong.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have

$$e^{(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})t}=\color{red}{\mathbf{I}}+(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})t$$

Comment: Ooooops, thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

The exponential matrix of 
$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$
is not correct: 
$e^{\mathbf{A}t}\not=\begin{bmatrix}
te^t & -te^t\\
0 & te^t
\end{bmatrix}.$
It should be
$$e^{\mathbf{A}t}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\mathbf{A}^n\frac{t^n}{n!}=
\sum_{n\geq 0}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -n\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\frac{t^n}{n!}=
\begin{bmatrix}
e^t & -te^t\\
0 & e^t
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: See you again! :P